# PKCS15 certificates

Tags: security, smartcard

I read the PKCS15 standard but I am still confused on how to store certificates in a smartcard. Do certificates stored as binary on an EF? or it is a file and where is it stored if not in EF?

Answer (score 0):

There are tools in linux that allow you to manipulate pkcs15-capable smart cards:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/pkcs15-tool.1.html

Perhaps a closer look at these will help you.

Answer (score 0):

PKCS#15 or the international standard ISO 7816-15 that succeeds it is a kind of directory structure for file based smart cards. Within it, certificates are normally stored in (transparent) EF's as you guessed, and if there is a corresponding private key, it is stored as an object within a DF.

Comment: Anything wrong with my answer john? Don't forget to followup, and if you have a good answer (in your opinion) please hit accept...